# R: Converting from Excel Solver to lpSolve

Tags: r, lpsolve

Until recently, my R usage was limited to plotting with ggplot etc. At the moment, I'm trying to solve linear problems with R using lpSolve, which proves to be quite the challenge. I'm trying to achieve similar results as I got with the Solver in MS Excel.

What I've got:

A: a 20x6 matrix with observations.

```
> head(Filtered)
    C1   C2    C3     C4     C5   C6
1 15.6 17.6  12.0   12.0   27.8 15.0
2 20.0 18.2  10.7    9.3   17.8 24.0
3 20.5 19.5  11.3   10.8   17.2 20.7
4 21.3 20.9  11.6   10.5   19.7 15.9
5 26.7 28.7  14.9   10.2    8.9 10.5
6 25.5 28.1  14.7    9.9    9.9 11.9
```

B: a 20x1 vector with observations.

```
> measSSA
 [1] 19.4 29.3 29.5 33.9 51.0 45.0 30.8 39.9 31.3 41.3 33.1 32.6 36.9 35.6 41.3 27.7 35.0 27.8 34.6 13.4
```

c: a 6x1 vector with constrained decision variables

```
> c
[1] 0.95 2.79 3.91 5.74 5.29 5.64
```

d: a 6x1 vector with constrained decision variables

```
> d
[1]  0.0022  4.0000 10.7000 21.1000 44.5000 70.6000
```

I then calculate simulated values for each element in B based on the corresponding row in A and vectors c and d.

```
Constant = 0.00377
Result = t(t((Constant*A)%*%diag(c))/d)
Simulated = rowSums(Result)
```

What I then want to do is minimize the mean square error between B and the simulated vector, which would give me the optimal fit.

```
MSE = sum((B-Simulated)^2)/20
```

What I would like to do with lpSolve is vary the values of the vectors c and d to minimize the MSE. However, although I am able to put in vectors c and d as constraining variables with lpSolve, I am not able to set MSE as the minimization objective. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Best to include sample data and show what you attempted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: How do you model a mean squared error in lpSolve?

Comment: I have added some of my data and code. I hope this clarifies what I want to do.